# Why can SDK not resolve Id as a symbol?

Tags: android, sdk

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
       case new R.Id():Imagebutton();
            ImageButtonClick();
            break;

    }
}

private void Imagebutton() {
}
```

I'm quite new to Android SDK and this may be a minor issue but I keep getting this error "Cannot Resolve Symbol 'Id'".

I'm currently trying to design a button which opens another activity, I've been following a tutorial and I've followed all the instructions but these Id errors keep appearing?

Any Help would be great,

**Burning Flame,**

Comment: I would presume that `R.Id():Imagebutton();` should be replaced with `R.id.imagebutton:`.

Comment: Ok I added that and it came up with '(' or '[' was expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you're using Id() instead of Id.

Comment: Yeh that solved the main issue thanks! But now it came up with '(' or '[' was expected at the end of R.id.imagebutton:

Comment: It's because you use ; instead of : at the end of your line, I think :) Also, if it worked, could you mark my answer as accepted ? ^^

Comment: Sure! Sos new to the system :D

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can access a resource:

In code: Using a static integer from a sub-class of your R class, such as:

```
R.string.hello
```

string is the resource type and hello is the resource name. There are many Android APIs that can access your resources when you provide a resource ID in this format. [See Accessing Resources in Code.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromCode)

In XML: Using a special XML syntax that also corresponds to the resource ID defined in your R class, such as:
@string/hello
string is the resource type and hello is the resource name. You can use this syntax in an XML resource any place where a value is expected that you provide in a resource. [See Accessing Resources from XML.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromXml)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
       case R.id.YourIdName;
            ImageButtonClick();
            break;

    }
}

private void Imagebutton() {
}
```